# Cast object without any more info than its System.Type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types, extension-methods

For a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929763/updating-observablecollection-item-properties-using-inotifypropertychanged) i quite recently wrote a generic extension method that should load an object from another, i.e. assign all the properties of the source to the target and do so recursively if the property is a reference-type. I got quite far using reflection but i hit a problem when it came to the types of properties that are reference-types, here is my first approach:

First approach:

```
    public static void Load<T>(this T target, T source, bool deep)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.CanWrite && property.CanRead)
            {
                if (!deep || property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || property.PropertyType == typeof(String))
                {
                    property.SetValue(target, property.GetValue(source, null), null);
                }
                else
                {
                    property.GetValue(target, null).Load(property.GetValue(source, null), deep);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that `PropertyInfo.GetValue` returns an object, subsequently `T` will equal `object` in the recursive call and i can no longer get the properties that the object actually has.

I conceived of a workaround which requires you to pass the Type explicitly, which is quite redundant since in theory it should be possible to manage without:

```
    public static void Load<T>(this T target, Type type, T source, bool deep)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.CanWrite && property.CanRead)
            {
                if (!deep || property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || property.PropertyType == typeof(String))
                {
                    property.SetValue(target, property.GetValue(source, null), null);
                }
                else
                {
                    object targetPropertyReference = property.GetValue(target, null);
                    targetPropertyReference.Load(targetPropertyReference.GetType(), property.GetValue(source, null), deep);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I also tried using `dynamic targetPropertyReference` but then i get a runtime exception that the `Load` method cannot be found, it is infuriating.

Other than that `Convert.ChangeType` handily returns a bloody `object` too and i cannot seem to otherwise cast the object to what it is. Of course i have looked for an answer to this on the net but i have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked at the full code or considered the full consequences of implementing such a scheme (EDIT: what will happen if there are cyclic references?), but I can give you two short fixes for your *specific* problem:

**Option 1: Dodge the issue**

Use the run-time type of the provided "normal" argument, rather than the *type-argument*.

Replace:

```
typeof(T).GetProperties()
```

with:

```
// You need null-checks around this:
// you can't realistically continue if target is null anyway.
target.GetType().GetProperties()
```

This of course introduces a *minor* semantic change in your code, in that it prevents scenarios when one would would want to pass a `Giraffe` but only want `Animal` properties copied over. It will also blow up if `source` and `target` are of different run-time types (having different properties), but you can work around that without too much trouble (e.g. find the deepest common base-type and use *its* properties instead).

---

**Option 2: More reflection / dynamic**

The other solution of course, is to use `MakeGenericMethod` to allow the type-argument to be provided "dynamically". This maintains the original semantics of the code (untested):

```
typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("Load")
               .MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType)
               .Invoke(null, property.GetValue(target, null), 
                             property.GetValue(source, null), deep);
```

---

Btw, there's *no* reason you can't use `dynamic` to accomplish something very similar. I suspect you're trying to do the call "as" an extension-method, [but that won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258988/will-the-dynamic-keyword-in-c4-support-extension-methods). Just try the normal "static-method" syntax.

Comment: No way! I thought i had tried `target.GetType()`, thank you very much! That will do i think (i mean, if something is boxed how likely is it that this has been done just to change all the supertype specific properties only to unbox it later). Will not mark this as answer since it does not answer the actual question (or does it?), i'll change the question itself though if no answer turns up in, say, a month.

Comment: @H.B.: It would be great if you could tell me how this doesn't answer the question. I think option 2 does what you want while maintaining the semantics of the code.

Comment: I not familiar with what you do in Option 2, so i'll just take it from you that these are indeed the droids i'm looking for :)

Comment: @H.B.: That was a genuine question from me, not a way to ask for an accepted answer.

Comment: @H.B.: Essentially, option 2 figures out what `T` should be at run-time, creates a version of the method with *that* type argument, and then invokes it.

Comment: On a side note, could it be that the second solution is a bit more expensive in terms of performance? Obviously it's more code but it's just reflection after all so i can't really make an estimate.

Comment: About your earlier comments, i know it was, but i'm not as experienced with reflection as you are so i cannot tell. Also i even understood option 2 after reading it a few times. Well, it does not really matter if this qualifies as "casting", now does it?

Comment: @H.B.: It's unclear what you mean by "casting" means in this context. You don't know the types of the properties before hand - this is an inherently dynamic scenario.

Comment: Indeed, good job pointing out that i apparently don't even know what that means :P

Comment: @H.B.: I really think this idea will have problems if there are any cycles.

Comment: OK, i'll be sticking to the first anyway i think, thanks again!